# Pretty printing list of heterogeneous parameters

Tags: haskell, pretty-print, string-interpolation

I am using the `prettyprinter` Haskell library and I have a heterogeneous set of parameters. How can I abstract away these long chains of concatenation?

```
pretty foo <+> pretty bar <+> pretty baz
```

Note that I cannot get `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` into a list (for example, to `foldMap` them), since they may be different types. A heterogeneous list may be a  solution, but I worry about the potential typeclass overhead.

Is there an idiom I can apply here? A proper method of string interpolation would also be useful.

Comment: If all of your uses are 'lists' of known length, then using heterogenous lists, e.g. something like `hfoldMap pretty [foo,bar,baz]` would have no more overhead than the simple solution. But if that's the case (only lists of known length), in my opinion, writing such code is more trouble than it's worth. For the string interpolation solution, see [Text.Printf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html) - basically the exact same implementation should work for you. And I think e.g. `prettyPrintf "%s %s %s" foo bar baz` looks pretty nice.

Comment: You could define a custom typeclass with a custom operator `<+++> :: a -> b  -> Doc` which applies `pretty` as needed and calls `<+>`. Note that this is convenient only if you have a small amount of types, since you'll have to define the instance for every combination of e.g. `Int,Bool,String,Doc`, which grows quadratically. Or some `Typeable` check. I'm not sure this is worth it, though. The original code is simple enough to justify solutions which are "too clever".

Comment: You only need two instances, one for `Doc`, and one for all other `Pretty` types.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Overlapping instances are quite fragile, and I'd tend to avoid them if I can.

Comment: @chi What's wrong with `<+++> :: (Prettiable a, Prettiable b) => a -> b -> Doc`?

Comment: @immibis That would require `Pretty Doc` but the library does not define that instance. I don't know why. If that can be added, with `pretty=id`, the approach you suggest would be the best, I think.